# Wait for file content of multiple files

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise, async-await, filereader

I would like to read the file content of multiple files and return the content as an array. 
The whole process should wait until all file contents are received. 
My function works somehow only with one file as input. 
As soon as I enter more thean one file to `getFileContent` I receive only the result of the first file. 
Could someone give me a hint what I'm missing in my construct?

```
interface FileInterface {
  fileName: string;
  fileContent: string | ArrayBuffer | null;
}

async function readFileAsync(file: File): Promise<string | ArrayBuffer | null> {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let fileReader: FileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = () => {
      resolve(fileReader.result);
    };
    fileReader.onerror = reject;
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  });
}

export async function getFileContent(
  files: File[]
): Promise<Array<FileInterface>> {
  const uploadedFiles: FileInterface[] = [];
  for (let file of files) {
    console.log(file.name);
    let fileContent: ArrayBuffer = (await readFileAsync(file)) as ArrayBuffer;
    uploadedFiles.push({ fileName: file.name, fileContent: null });
  }

  return uploadedFiles;
}

// files: File[]
const fileContents: FileInterface[] = await getFileContent(files);
```

Comment: Are you able to see file names of all the files? using your `console.log(file.name)`?

Comment: Yes, but all the time only one name.

Comment: Then it might be the case that files is only an array of one file, try printing files.length

Comment: That is not the problem. As soon as I comment out the line `let fileContent: ArrayBuffer = (await readFileAsync(file)) as ArrayBuffer;` I see all file names.

Comment: Is the top level `files` modified elsewhere?

Comment: No should not be because I'm able to see all names if I remove the line `let fileContent: ArrayBuffer = (await readFileAsync(file)) as ArrayBuffer;`.

Comment: It's possible that it's modified elsewhere during the await suspension since the files are intact when it's not interrupted.

Comment: @concat: that was the hint. I'm using react and there is `value=""` on the file input defined. I was using the `event.target.files` as input for the function and the component was rerendering...

Comment: Ah okay, glad you got it working. I'll post a brief answer to summarize that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a discussion in the question's comments, we found the root of the issue is the suspension while reading the first file (`await readFileAsync(file)`) that allowed the React input component from which `files` comes from to rerender and wipe `files` in-place.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to mix in promises, why not use the new promise based file/blob [reading methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) and screw the fileReader all together? Another solution would be to do: `new Response(file).arrayBuffer()`

```
// Simulate files you would get from input[type=file]
files = [
  new File(['a'], 'a.txt'),
  new File(['b'], 'b.txt')
]

const fileContents = await Promise.all(files.map(file => file.arrayBuffer().then(buf => ({
  fileContent: buf,
  fileName: file.name
}))))
```

...All doe i would not have read all those files into memory if it wasn't necessary... if it's for uploading then i would just add those into a FormData instead.